# Google Calendar API stopped returning events

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-explorer

Since today I have problem with one of 2 similar calls to Google Calendar API v3:

```
calendar.events.list
```

Both calls are requesting list of assignemnts and use privateExtendedProperty to filter them, but key=Value pairs are different.

When I have **privateExtendedProperty** set to **myStatus=READY** it returns events I need,
but when I set **privateExtendedProperty** to **myId=agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYkcHA3wgM**
it returns no events, though I'm sure there are several events with this myId...

It appears that the calendar API list is returning an empty list when querying by a privateExtendedProperty with 90 characters long.

Everything worked fine for years, but it suddenly broke for some of my users this morning...

This is my request:

```
GET googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/****/events?privateExtendedProperty=myId%3Dagxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYwauk6QgM&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This is the result I see in API explorer:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"*****\"",
 "summary": "*****",
 "description": "*****",
 "updated": "2018-02-20T03:18:35.098Z",
 "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
 "accessRole": "owner",
 "defaultReminders": [
 ],
 "nextSyncToken": "CJDv1KDEs9kCEJDv1KDEs9kCGAU=",
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

**Update 1:**
My privateExtendedProperty looks like this:

```
{
  "myStatus": "READY",
  "myId": "agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYkcHA3wgM",
  "another": "Another value",
  "another2": "Another value2"
}
```

When I query events with "myStatus=READY" - event is returned, but when I do the same with "myId=agxzfm1..." - it returns emtpy list.

**Update 2:**
For those who have the same issue. As per suggestion, I created a new calendar and then duplicated some test data and tried long value in privateExtendedProperty query and it returned event as expected. It means, if this is a bug - not all calendars are affected and moving things to a new calendar might be a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

[The document for Extended Properties](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/extended-properties#limits) says the limitations as follows.

> 1. The maximum size of a property's key is 44 characters, and properties with longer keys will be silently dropped.
> 2. The maximum size of a property's value is 1024 characters, and properties with longer values will be silently truncated.
> 3. An event can have up to 300 shared properties totaling up to 32kB in size (keys size + value size).
> 4. An event can have up to 300 private properties, totaling up to 32kB in size (keys size + value size), across all "copies" of the event.

From this, it seems that your case is out of the above limitations. In my environment, also I tried your situation. As the result, it was found that `myId=agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYkcHA3wgM` can be used.

So can you confirm the following points again?

1. It seems that your result retrieved by API explorer doesn't included `extendedProperties` in the property of `items`. When you set `extendedProperties`, it can be seen. If you use `fields`, it might be not able to be seen.
2. Can you set `extendedProperties` with `myId=agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYkcHA3wgM` again?

   - You can set it using `calendar.events.patch`.
3. When you retrieve events with `myId=agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYkcHA3wgM` using `calendar.events.list`, if you use the URL encoded value of `myId%3dagxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYkcHA3wgM`, please try to use the value without URL encode.

If this was not useful for you and I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

- If you retrieve the event using `calendar.events.get`, can the extendedProperties you set be seen? If you cannot see it, please insert extendedProperties again.

  - The endpoint is `GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/### calendar Id ###/events/### event Id ###?fields=extendedProperties%2Fprivate`
- In my environment, the same endpoint of yours works fine. So as a test, can you try to create new calendar and run that query? Because I worried whether the recent update of calendar affects this situation.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have found the issue, someone already reported it as a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73128573
Google API returns items:[ ] for values over 69 characters...

Comment: myId is 4 characters --> under 44 characters.
my value is 92 characters --> under 1024 characters.

This is my request: 
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/****/events?privateExtendedProperty=myId%3Dagxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYwauk6QgM&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: @Evgeny Vostok Thank you for your additional information. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. I would like to expect that this problem doesn't depend on each account of users.

Comment: I tried your request and it returns extendedProperties/private fine. It also returns list of items fine with all extendedProperties, if privateExtendedPropery value is shorter than 70 characters...

Comment: @Evgeny Vostok Thank you for trying. In your situation, privateExtendedProperty can be confirmed using ``calendar.events.get``. But ``calendar.events.list`` cannot find the key and value of privateExtendedProperty. For example, when both ``myStatus=READY`` and ``myId=agxzfm1haWxmb29nYWVyNQsSDE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIVYWN0aXZlZ2FtaW5nbWVkaWEuY29tDAsSBENhc2UYkcHA3wgM`` for privateExtendedProperty are installed, the event retrieved by ``myStatus=READY`` has another privateExtendedProperty? I'm sorry for taiking your time.

Comment: Yes, my privateExtendedProperty has like 30 key=Value pairs, when I query key=Value, where Value is short - it returns event fine, when I query key=Value, where Value is over 70 characters - it returns nothing.

Comment: Do you install 30 pairs of privateExtendedProperty to one event?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine for ages, basically I keep all the information I need about the event in ExtendedProperties and use it to render my UI. I updated the question with example of my extendedproperties object.

Comment: @Evgeny Vostok Thank you for the additional information. Unfortunately, in my environment, I couldn't reproduce your situation. If the difference between your environment and my one is found, we may be able to obtain something to solve this problem. But I apologize for this incomplete situation.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I created a new calendar as per your suggestion and added extendedProperty in there and tried to calendar.events.list with extendedProperty in query - and long value worked. So, running query in old calendar returned empty, but same query in new calendar returned the event I expected. Probably I'll have to move everything to a new calendar tomorrow and give it another shot.

Comment: @Evgeny Vostok Thank you for your additional information. My last worry of my answer could be used? ``In my environment, the same endpoint of yours works fine. So as a test, can you try to create new calendar and run that query? Because I worried whether the recent update of calendar affects this situation.`` If you didn't notice it, I'm sorry for my poor English skill, and I'm really sorry for taking your time.